# What Files Were Read/Written Under the Linux Root Path without File Name

Tags: filesystems, kernel, inode

I am trying to monitor the read/write behaviors by printing out some messages from file system under Linux kernel site, like in "fs/read_write.c".

To print out file name information, I use `file->f_path.dentry->d_iname` to find the current file name and `dentry_path_raw(file->f_path.dentry,buff,256)` to have the file path.

It worked fine but I found some read/write WITHOUT a file name under root path like `path="/"` & `filename=""`. (sometimes the filename comes with `[eventfd]`) They are always from `pos=0` and read/write with a small count/length (mostly 4, 8, or 16) by `uid=0`(system) or `uid=1000`(user).

What could possibly be these files or behaviors? Is it possible to know the file names of them?

---

(edited)
I am collecting these read/write behaviors as a log file to our project, checking them if they are useful information for us or not. Therefore, I am wondering what are these files without any name appeared. In the log we saw many records like:

```
timestamp(s,ns), r/w, file_path, count, pos
1561655986,735903193,w,/,1,0
1561655986,735910768,w,/,1,0
1561655986,735919919,r,/,10,0
1561655986,735926298,r,/,10,0
1561655986,737899450,w,/,8,0
1561655986,738076093,r,/,16,0
1561655986,744518278,r,/dri/card1,1024,0
```

By using `lsof`, I could find few lines working under the root path like:

```
dconf\x20 4222 4223             user  rtd       DIR              259,2     4096          2 /
...
gmain     4222 4224             user  rtd       DIR              259,2     4096          2 /
...
pulseaudi 4268                  user  cwd       DIR              259,2     4096          2 /
pulseaudi 4268                  user  rtd       DIR              259,2     4096          2 /
```

Are they just some temporary files? Why they don't have any file name?

Comment: file descriptors can be used by anonymous pipes, sockets, and special features such as eventfd, inotify, eventpoll (just look at the output of `lsof` for examples) - you might want to add context as to what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Let me put more information to the question site.

Comment: Regarding your second question: `man lsof` and searching e.g. `rtd` will tell you that these aren't open file descriptors (at least on Linux). Regarding the first question, I still don't understand what you're looking for. If you already know of e.g. eventfd, does that not answer the "files with no name" question?

Comment: I just realized that your first comment has already answered my questions. I am working on this with `lsof` now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lsof` provides the info/list of my system and I can do searches based on that. Thanks.